# Rest API resource naming convention

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, restful-architecture, restful-url

I have a students table which contains all his basic details with below schema. SsnId is the primary key

```
{"name" : "Jack",
"age" : 10,
"ssnId": "12345"
}
```

I have another table `students_by_region`. A student can belong to multiple regions. The region is the primary key.

```
{
"region" : "Atlanta",
"studentSet" : [Student A, Student B]
}
```

Need help to define rest APIs for the above tables for below use cases

1. Get Me all students of X region.
2. Add a student to a particular region.
3. Create a region with a student.

Comment: (a) this is not a code-for-me service, and (b) don't expect us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score -3):

1) Fetching list of all students ->

```
GET /students
```

2) Creating a new student by posting a JSON request body ->

```
POST /regions/<regionID>/students
```

3) Would split that into two:

```
POST /regions
```

to create a new region followed by

```
POST /regions/<newRegionID>/students
```